# Batch file to: Read inputs, test them, save result to txt?

Tags: windows, batch-file

what im trying to do is:

1. input.txt
2. test.bat
3. output.txt

> ```
> @echo off
>
> setlocal
>
> set "SECRET=for /f "delims=" %%L in (input.txt)"  // reads text line by line //
>
> set "URL=curl --data-binary '' "http:localhost:port/page?requestType=SECRET=" // a line from input.txt will be set after SECRET= to test then move to another line
> ```
>
> etc..//
>
> ```
> set "LOG=C:\output.txt" // save results
>
> >"%LOG%"
> ```

i'm trying to make this work. any help please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

(for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
 echo curl --data-binary '' "http:localhost:port/page?requestType=SECRET=%%a
))>output.txt
```

EDIT :

I think you're trying to do this :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
 curl --data-binary '' "http:localhost:port/page?requestType=SECRET=%%a >output.txt
 for /f "tokens=6 delims=,:}" %%b in (output.txt) do (
        set "$Value3=%%b"
        echo !$Value3:~1,-1! >%%a_Result.txt
 )
```

This will save the value3 for each secret in `Secret_Result.txt`

Comment: GREAT! works exactly as i wanted! thanks,, now the result file have like this {"test":"value","test2":"value2","test3":value3"} how i can add a line that also will read the value3 from the result file and make same test and save to another file ? thanks

Comment: Great, but the output.txt comes in UTF-8 format so the %%a_Result.txt only shows the first value3 (tokens=6), also it there a way to show the value3 without ""

Comment: this wokrs, no more "", but the value3 is not static as you mentioned set "$Value3=%%b" the static one is test3 (examble: Name(test3):(value3)SachaDee ), im tying with this last issue, thanks!